# Oozie change action data path from S3 to hdfs on EMR

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-emr, oozie

We are using oozie  to run our workflows and EMR as our cluster service.

In the job logs observed that all the action data is written  to S3 at the following path 
user/oozie/oozie-oozi/${wf-id}/${action-name}--spark/${wf-id}@${action-name}@0

Is there a  configuration to change the above path from S3 to hdfs  in oozie-site.xml
All the workflows are present in S3.

Comment: _"all the action data ... `${action-name}--spark`"_ > what do you mean by "action data"? E.g. if you want your Spark jobs to use a specific scratch dir, then you should set a Spark property, not an Oozie property...

Comment: Hi Samson the logs mentioned in my description are from  oozie launcher ,if it is hive  action it will be somethig like --hive/${wf-id}, per oozie source code base path is fetched from   launcher conf and property name is oozie.action.dir.path i tried to override this in oozie-site but not luck,